# How do I get values out of a flutter List<class>?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I am trying to make an app using GetX in Flutter.
However, after sorting the values using the where operator in a List that has a structure of Class, I try to save it as a List and use it.

In my current code, the String displayed in the Text widget is **"Instance of 'Product'"**.
I hope you guys can tell me how to retrieve the stored value in a simple way without running a for loop.

**Model and List Data are as follows.**

```
class Product {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final String description;
  final double price;
  final String imageUrl;
  bool isFavorite;

  Product({
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
    required this.description,
    required this.price,
    required this.imageUrl,
    this.isFavorite = false,
  });
}

List<Product> lodedProduct = [
  Product(
    id: 'p1',
    title: 'Red Shirt',
    description: 'A red shirt - it is pretty red!',
    price: 29.99,
    imageUrl:
        'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/10/02/22/17/red-t-shirt-1710578_1280.jpg',
  ),
  Product(
    id: 'p2',
    title: 'Trousers',
    description: 'A nice pair of trousers.',
    price: 59.99,
    imageUrl:
        'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e8/Trousers%2C_dress_%28AM_1960.022-8%29.jpg/512px-Trousers%2C_dress_%28AM_1960.022-8%29.jpg',
  ),
  Product(
    id: 'p3',
    title: 'Yellow Scarf',
    description: 'Warm and cozy - exactly what you need for the winter.',
    price: 19.99,
    imageUrl: 'https://live.staticflickr.com/4043/4438260868_cc79b3369d_z.jpg',
  ),
  Product(
    id: 'p4',
    title: 'A Pan',
    description: 'Prepare any meal you want.',
    price: 49.99,
    imageUrl:
        'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/14/Cast-Iron-Pan.jpg/1024px-Cast-Iron-Pan.jpg',
  ),
];
```

**The part to be displayed is as follows.**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:myshop/data/product_data.dart';

import '../models/product.dart';

class ProductDetailScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  ProductDetailScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  var filteredList = lodedProduct
      .where((element) => element.id.contains(Get.arguments))
      .map((e) => e)
      .toList();
//Here, get the id from the previous page with Get.arguments. id is the 0th id in the List.

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text(Get.arguments),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          child: Text(filteredList.toString()),
//Here, I want to get the value of filteredList as a string.
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: filteredList.map((e){
            return Text(e.title);
          }).toList(),
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: The following message appears.
The argument type 'Iterable<Text>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<Widget>'.

Comment: Hey @JunK...I've made an edit - I added `toList()`

Comment: Yes. This code works. Thank you so much.
But is it possible to call this code outside of the Text widget?
For example, Text(title) can only be called like this.

Comment: Uhm, not really since you're looping through the list.

Comment: I found a way to get the value outside the Text widget.

Answer (score 0):

```
final RxList<CustomModel> _list = <CustomModel>[].obs;

int getLength() {
  return _list?.length ?? 0;
}

String getImage(int index) {
  return _list?.value[index].image ?? "Nil";
}

String getTitle(int index) {
  return _list?.value[index].title ?? "Nil";
}



class CustomModel {
   CustomModel ({this.title, this.image})
   final String? title;
   final String? image;
}
```

Comment: you can check this link https://github.com/benedictcontawe/FlutterApp/tree/GetXHTTP

Answer (score -1):

Finally I found the answer.
The correct answer was to use firstWhere, not where.

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final productId =
        controller.items.firstWhere((element) => element.id == Get.arguments);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text(productId.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              width: double.maxFinite,
              height: 250,
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  image: NetworkImage(productId.imageUrl),
                ),
              ),
              child: Container(
                height: 50,
                width: double.maxFinite,
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3),
                child: Text(
                  productId.title,
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 30,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 20),
            Text(productId.description),
            const SizedBox(height: 20),
            Text('\$ ' + productId.price.toString()),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```